# Android USB Connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, android

I'm trying to establish a USB connection between my computer and my Android device; I've downloaded the SDK and what I believe to be the proper Samsung USB drivers.  I had `adb` working and I rooted my phone.  But during the process I had to keep reinstalling the USB drivers to get it to work; Windows keeps trying to install its own drivers and now I can't install any Samsung drivers. I tried using USBdeview, but it doesn't work. How do I properly install the Samsung drivers again or stop Windows from causing problems?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure that your Samsung android device is in USB debugging mode. You can turn it on or off through Settings > Applications > Development. Turning this on and off is sometimes all you need (especially if you got it to work before.)

2) Depends on what device you have. I have a Galaxy S and I've worked it. For other devices, I'm not so sure, but the protocol should be the same.

3) Download Samsung Kies (http://www.soft-files.com/samsung-kies_78273.html) It's not great (far from it), but it should eliminate the "Windows is unable to find a MTP USB device driver" problem as it will authenticate the device. To check you can always go to the command line and check 'adb devices' (assuming you have 'android device bridge' installed.)

4) Just download the drivers themselves. This worked for me. Also depends on what OS you're sporting. I've heard that Windows 7 x64 doesn't work too good with Kies. MTP USB driver issues seem to be current with 64 bits OS. I don't have x64 so I haven't tried it.

[For Windows 7](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x86.shtml)

[For Windows 7 x64](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x64.shtml)